# Why is text with same formattings rendered differently on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, media-queries

I experience a strange behavior where text with the same formatting is being displayed with different sizes on the iPhone (Safari)

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="page" id="thanks">
    <div class="subtext">
    <p>
        text tex text <!-- Being displayed with the correct size -->
    </p>
</div>
</div>


<div class="page" id="about">
    <div id="about_us">
        <div class="about_box" id="robi">
        <p> text text text</p> <!-- NOT being displayed with the correct size -->
        </div>
        <div class="about_box" id="andrea"><p class="header">Robi &uuml;ber Andrea, 25</p>
           <p> text text text </p> <!-- NOT being displayed with the correct size -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the according CSS:

```
body{ 
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'GaramondPremrProDisp', 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}



@media handheld and (orientation: portrait){
    body{ 
        background-color:#ffffff;
        font-family: 'GaramondPremrProDisp', 'EB Garamond', serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}

div.page{
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
}
div.page div.subtext{
    width: 68%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.page div.subtext p{
    text-align: center;
}

div#about div#about_us{
    width: 68%;
    height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div#about div.about_box{
    text-align: center;

    height: 450px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

As marked with comments in the HTML code... there is text which is affected by bigger `font-size` resulting from the media query and text which is not affected. The strange thing is, if I write `all` instead of `handheld` in the media query and test it on a desktop browser... ALL text is being affected by the rule so I guess it is not a selector problem.

I also tried everyting described in the answer of this question: [Fix font size issue on Mobile Safari (iPhone) where text is rendered inconsistently and some fonts are larger than others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303263/fix-font-size-issue-on-mobile-safari-iphone-where-text-is-rendered-inconsisten) (without any success).

edit: copied the described version to a folder in my dev environment which will not be affected by changes if you want to have a look at it live (veeeery slow): [Check it out!](http://robi.mooo.info/so/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Safari disregards the `handheld` selector in media queries. So the media query did not trigger at all. The text was displayed in different sizes because `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` did not trigger because it was inside the `@media handheld` query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` on the `body`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust
http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/

Comment: just added this to the question, sorry. Yes I did... without success.