# Font-size on mobile device

Tags: css, mobile

I set `font-size: 12px` on my body element. But on the mobile device some elements have a font-size of more than 12px (for example, element p). Why does this happen? How can this be fixed?

```
body {
   font: normal normal 400 12px/1.5 "Droid Sans", Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer {
    background: #1d3057;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #dedede;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
. footer span {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: pre;
   float: left;
   font-size: 12px;
```

}

Comment: Mobile devices adjust font sizes for legibility. You can force it to a desired size by targeting mobile devices in your CSS. [More information can be found in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540312/3125787).

Comment: Why does size change in span and only in Chrome and sometimes? 2 of the 4 Chrome doesn't change size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
* { max-height: 999999px; }
```